# MultiAutoCompleteTextView adapter notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

Is there a way to update a MultiAutoCompleteTextView's array adapter? I'm using the bellow code and it doesn't work. Please notice also that "emailList" is a String ArrayList. Thanks in advance

```
recipientsTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            final String selectedEmail = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            if (emailList.contains(selectedEmail)) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        emailList.remove(selectedEmail);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you using the TokenComplete component? https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete

If it is its because you to do some changes at the FilterAdapter.